# Coldfusion Struct getting only numeric key list

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a coldfusion Struct containing mix keys numeric and alpha, alphanumerics

I need to access only the numeric keys.

My code looks like

```
<cfset ids = structkeyList(st ) />
<cfset numericIDs = "" />
<cfloop list="#ids#" index="i">
    <cfif IsNumeric(i)>
        <cfset numericIDs = ListAppend( numericIDs , i ) />
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Is there a better method to solve such problems?

Comment: I'd use an array rather than a list, but other than that, that approach seems fine. There are better options with more recent versions of CF, but if yer stuck on CF9, so be it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a better method to solve such problems?

I would use something like this:

```
<cfset numericIDs = arrayToList(reMatch('\b\d+(?=,|$)\b', structKeyList(st)))>
```

Comment: This one is really handy.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a better method to solve such problems?

I'd generally recommend working with arrays instead of lists.

In CF9 a loop similar to yours is as good as it gets. You can make a utility function out of it if you need it more than once. This one avoids `StructKeyList()` to be able to deal with all kinds of keys, independent of a separator character:

```
<cfscript>
  function GetNumericKeys(struct) {
    var keys = struct.keys();
    var result = ArrayNew(1);
    var key = "";

    while (keys.hasNext()) {
      key = keys.next();
      if (IsNumeric(key)) ArrayAppend(result, key);
    }

    return result;
  }
</cfscript>
```

and

```
<cfset nkeys = GetNumericKeys(st)>
```

---

In CF11 you can get a little more sophisticated (tested on CF11, can't say how CF10 handles this code).

```
<cfscript>
  numericIDs = arrayFilter(structKeyArray(st), function (key) {
    return IsNumeric(key);
  });
</cfscript>
```

To ensure integer keys, use:

```
<cfscript>
  numericIDs = arrayFilter(structKeyArray(st), function (key) {
    return Int(key) eq key;
  });
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see what's wrong with this. It should work quite well already, and it is very readable.

Sometimes working with a List is faster than an Array.

Answer (score 0):

I had this:

```
<cfscript> function ListNumeric(principal) {
    a=principal;
        cleanlist = '';     for (i=1; i <= ListLen(a);i=i+1) {      if(IsNumeric(ListGetAt(a,i))){  cleanlist = ListAppend(cleanlist,ListGetAt(a,i));   }   }   Return cleanlist; } </cfscript>
```

Also possible to work with regular expression:

```
inList2 = REReplace(inList,"[^0-9.]", "","ALL");
```